# IntelliJ IDEA - How open Customize IDEA

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

During first launch IntelliJ IDEA opens convinient dialog for quick configuration "Customize IDEA".

How to open it any time?

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can open that specific window again, but all the settings are still available under Preferences, but they'll be organized differently.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you never need to open it again. As everything on this screen is enabled by default. When you create related project you will be able to use those features. There is always an option to uninstall followed by new install but don't forget to backup your setting.

Another trick is to rename or delete the local cache folder of Intellij Idea. This will force IntelliJ idea thinking its a new installation and it will ask you everything again. But you will loose your setting and have to enter licence details again.

In ubutnu local cache where IntelliJ store its meta-data is:

```
~/.IntelliJIdea15
```

Rename or move it and rerun intelliJ idea. You can restore it later if you want.